How to deserialize JSON to TJsonObject in Delphi 12?
I am trying to deserialize a JSON response into Delphi objects using TJson.JsonToObject. The structure of the response and the classes I'm using are shown below, along with the data structure I'm working with (see the attached image).
Data Structure:
ErrorAdditionalInfo



Name
Type
Description




info
object
The additional info.


type
string
The additional info type.



ErrorDetail



Name
Type
Description




additionalInfo
ErrorAdditionalInfo[]
The error additional info.


code
string
The error code.


details
ErrorDetail[]
The error details.


message
string
The error message.


target
string
The error target.



Here is the class structure:
  TErrorAdditionalInfo = class
  private
    FInfo: TJSONObject;
    FType: string;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Info: TJSONObject read FInfo;
    property &Type: string read FType;
  end;

  TErrorDetail = class
  private
    FAdditionalInfo: TArray<TErrorAdditionalInfo>;
    FCode: string;
    FDetails: TArray<TErrorDetail>;
    FMessage: string;
    FTarget: string;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property AdditionalInfo: TArray<TErrorAdditionalInfo> read FAdditionalInfo;
    property Code: string read FCode;
    property Details: TArray<TErrorDetail> read FDetails;
    property Message: string read FMessage;
    property Target: string read FTarget;
  end;

When I try to deserialize the JSON string into the Delphi object using the following code:
var Err := TJson.JsonToObject<TErrorDetail>(AResponseString);

All members are deserialized correctly except for TErrorAdditionalInfo.FInfo, which remains empty. I expect this field to be populated with a TJSONObject containing the info object from the JSON response.
How can I correctly deserialize the info object as a TJsonObject in FInfo? Is it possible to achieve this using REST.Json, or is there another approach I should take (i.e. parse all these objects manually)?
The JSON I am willing to serialize looks like:
{
  "additionalInfo": {
    "info": {
      "Key1": "TextValue",
      "Key2": 123,
      "Key3": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    "type": "SomeType"
  },
  "code": "some code",
  "details": [],
  "message": "Hello world",
  "target": ""
}

I expect TJsonObject to contain the following data:
{
  "Key1": "TextValue",
  "Key2": 123,
  "Key3": [1, 2, 3]
}


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Can you provide an example JSON that you are trying to deserialize?

Thanks for your remark, @KenWhite, I'll follow this rule in the future.

@RemyLebeau I added an example.

Unfortunately JsonToObject doesn't support to get hands on the original JSON content during conversion. AFAIK, there is no way to achieve what you want with TJson.JsonToObject unless you know the actual class type behind addtitionalinfo.type.

If FInfo is always the same Structure, why don't you build a Class for that as well and use it instead of TJSONObject?
A simple Class represents a JSONObject.

If Info has the same Structure every time. Use a Class for that.
Type
TInfo = class
  private
    FKey1: string;
    FKey2: integer;
    FKey3: Tarray<Integer>;
  public
    property Key1: String read FKey1;
    property Key2: Integer read FKey2;
    property Key3: TArray<Integer> read FKey3;
  end;

TErrorAdditionalInfo = class
  private
    FInfo: TInfo ;
    FType: string;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Info: TInfo read FInfo;
    property &Type: string read FType;
  end;
...

